# How to display array as text? - Laravel

Tags: arrays, laravel, database

[image: table data]

I tried this way to show this the data but it's not working:

Blade file:

```
@foreach($test->item['0'] as $link)
{{ $link['item1'] }}
@endforeach
```

Controller file:

```
public function testingview()
{
    $test = Test::get()->toArray();
    return view('Admin.test')->with('test', $test);
}
```

I want to show something like that:

Item1: 123, adsf, dd, abcd
Item2: on, on, true, true

Comment: use ```implode()``` function

Comment: As @PsyLogic said, you can use implode() or you can try use `@if($loop->last) {{ $link['item1'] }} @else {{ $link['item1'] }}, @endif`

Comment: @Kafus it tried the function you have posted, but it's showing: "Trying to get property 'test' of non-object"

i'll try to use implode() function, can you guys please send me a reference? that will big help.

thanks

Comment: have you tried `var_dump()`?

Comment: @kapitan yes, but i don't know how to show it here :?

Comment: `{{ var_dump($link['item1']) }}`

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```
@foreach($test->item['0'] as $link)
    Item 1: {{ implode(" ,", $link['item1']) }}
@endforeach
```

The implode function takes an array, puts it together, and returns it as a string. I encourage you to read more about [implode()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php).

Comment: Thanks for reply, but it's showing: Property [item] does not exist on this collection instance.  :(